# Create s scheduled task(Plesk) or cron job in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, scheduled-tasks, plesk

I have a woocommerce and i use berocket product filters plugin. The plugin has a button that purge cache in its setting page. I want to create a scheduled task from inside plesk that hosts the woocommerce that trigger that function every 30 minutes.

I have located,i think, the function that use the above button but i need help creating the scheduled task.

I have the function in the main.php file located in the root directory of the plugin.

```
public function section_purge_cache ( $item, $options ) {
    $html = '<tr>
        <th scope="row">' . __('Purge Cache', 'BeRocket_AJAX_domain') . '</th>
        <td>';
    $old_filter_widgets = get_option('widget_berocket_aapf_widget');
    if( ! is_array($old_filter_widgets) ) {
        $old_filter_widgets = array();
    }
    foreach ($old_filter_widgets as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_numeric($key)) {
            unset($old_filter_widgets[$key]);
        }
    }
    $html .= '
            <span class="button berocket_purge_cache" data-time="'.time().'">
                <input class="berocket_purge_cache_input" type="hidden" name="br_filters_options[purge_cache_time]" value="'.br_get_value_from_array($options, 'purge_cache_time').'">
                ' . __('Purge Cache', 'BeRocket_AJAX_domain') . '
            </span>
            <p>' . __('Clear attribute/custom taxonomy cache for plugin', 'BeRocket_AJAX_domain') . '</p>
            <script>
                jQuery(".berocket_purge_cache").click(function() {
                    var $this = jQuery(this);
                    if( ! $this.is(".berocket_ajax_sending") ) {
                        $this.attr("disabled", "disabled");
                        var time = $this.data("time");
                        $this.parents(".br_framework_submit_form").addClass("br_reload_form");
                        $this.find(".berocket_purge_cache_input").val(time).submit();
                    }
                });
            </script>
        </td>
    </tr>';
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a product from BeRocket i would suggest you to ask this question in the support forum of the plugin itself.

Here you go: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce-ajax-filters/